# python tkinter showing message without pausing program

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to write a program with python tkinter.
I wonder if it's possible to show a message or window without pausing the program?

For example, I want to show the status of the program (starting, waiting, finished)
but it seems like when the 'waiting' message/window is displaying, the program won't continue unless I close the window manually.

This is what I have now

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry('200x200')
root.configure(bg='gray92')
root.mainloop()
print(1)

root1 = Tk()
root1.geometry('200x200')
Message(root1, text="waiting...").pack()
root1.mainloop()
print(2)
```

I had to close the second window to print 2.

Is it possible to print 2 without closing the second window??

Comment: You can use ```.after()```

Comment: @Sujay thank you for your comment but Im not asking for the way to close the window.

Comment: ```.after()``` doesn't close the window.

Comment: @Sujay can you please explain you idea more detailed

Comment: ```root1.after(<milliseconds>,<function>)```

Comment: @Sujay what should I put in <function> in my case?

Comment: @Sujay You sure You meant `root1`? it still wouldn't be accessible until the first mainloop was done, which is partially the issue in that I would say that creating messages like this is not suggested, first of there is no need for multiple mainloops, second use maybe `Toplevel` and also at the end there is a `tkinter.simpledialog` module that can already provide some simple messaging stuff so maybe check that out. also is there really a need for two separate windows?

Comment: Why a message? There are things like Statusbar (basically a label with changing text) and [Progressbar](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/ttk-Progressbar.html).